# Flutter: Scroll Controller AnimateTo function doesn't alway reach desired position

Tags: flutter, scrollview, flutter-layout

I am using this code in my flutter project to animate my ListView to the bottom.

```
controller.animateTo(controller.position.maxScrollExtent,
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
```

The problem is this function doesn't seem to always reach the specified offset position. It can sometimes fall short by a little, and sometimes fall short by alot. I am certain i am not changing the maxScrollExtent of the ListView throughout the duration of the animation. Also another thing to keep in mind is my listView is extremely long.

Any ideas what might be causing this and how i might fix it.

Comment: you probably will be having some padding around your scrollable widget which is causing your position to shift a bit every time you animate.

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma i have a AnimatedPadding wrapped around my ListView and some padding as a parameter of the listView, Although the animated padding doesnt change throughout the course of the AnimateTo animation. Any ideas how i might fix this issue without removing the padding?

Comment: @UTKARSHSharma as i test run i just set both the animating Padding and the padding parameter of ListView to EdgeInsets.zero and was still getting the same issue

Comment: the simple solution is to remove the padding around the listview and insert the padding on the inner items (inner tiles or containers which are in listview) . this will serve your purpose.

Comment: Are you just scrolling to the bottom? or also other positions?

Comment: @ltk Just to the bottom ?

Comment: Is your listview item fixed in height? Do your listview items contain any network images or any other async widgets?

Comment: @ltk no, the listview contains a range of different widgets with different variable heights.

Comment: In that case, have you ever checked whether you scrollcontroller's maxscrollextent will change if you scroll or jump to any locations? Scrollcontroller's maxscrollextent is not a constant and it will change with the listview's children. As you have a list of widgets with different height, then it is better to check if the height of the weight is fixed throughout its life cycle. If it is dynamically changing, then I reckon the scrollcontroller cannot get itself updated and thus finally landing at a wrong position.

Comment: I have mentioned about network images and async widgets, because these widgets will not occupy any space before they are loaded. When you jump to any position in the listview, these widgets may not actually be built yet and results in a strange behaviour.